# loading an ASPX page into a jQuery UI Tab with AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I have some experience with jquery and regular html pages but only just started learning .net. I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a good tutorial or example of how to load aspx pages into jquery ui tabs with ajax. I have a Main.aspx page which has some jquery ui tabs for navigation. I would like to load the content for each tab with ajax. I have tried to use the [Ajax mode](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode) of jquery ui tabs but it seems like when the aspx page contains certain web controls it does not load for some reason. The aspx file that I want to load into the tab only has a button control that, when clicked, changes it's text to say "hello".

Here is the tab section of Main.aspx:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="test.aspx"><span>Test</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-2">Second Tab</div>
   <div id="tabs-3">Third Tab</div>
</div>
```

Here is the the test.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="TropicalServerGUI.test" %>
<div>
    <asp:button ID="btn" runat="server" text="Button" />
</div>
```

and its code-behind:

```
namespace TropicalServerGUI {
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //btn.Text = "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

the second and third tabs which are static work fine but nothing gets loaded into the first tab. If I were to remove the button control and put, for example, `<h1>Hello World</h1>` then it loads the page correctly. I know I am doing something completely wrong  and I cannot find any website that addresses this topic, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your code works in my machine. your `test.aspx` only needs the full html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialising the JQueryUI tabs?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I initialized the tabs. My problem is the two tabs with static content look fine but the one where the aspx file is loaded is empty.